# Macro Do loop not working properly in RSUBMIT

Tags: sas, sas-macro

So I have this code that works well for one year, but I need to convert it as a loop so it works for years from 1970 to 2015.

Here is the code for 1 year that I specify in a  %let statement.

```
%let year=1970
rsubmit; 
data home.historical_returns_&year;
set home.crspdata;
where (year <= &year - 1) and (year >= &year - 5);
returns_count + 1;
by id year;
if first.id or missing(tot_ret) then returns_count = 1;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

So far, that code works great for me. Now, I am trying to use a loop so I do it for year 1970 to 2015.

I have came up with this. Which looks like it works great, but the year stays at 1970.

```
%macro GMV;
rsubmit;
%do year=1970 %to 2015;
data home.historical_returns_&year;
set home.crspdata;
where (year <= &year - 1) and (year >= &year - 5);
returns_count + 1;
by id year;
if first.id or missing(tot_ret) then returns_count = 1;
run;
%end;
endrsubmit;

%mend GMV;

%GMV
```

In the log, I see that the &year in the name never actually changes from 1970 to 1971 to 1972 and so on. So I do not end up with the 45 different datasets that I need.

Anybody ever had this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of the macro variable YEAR in the remote SAS session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up remote processing with local processing in a way that's going to cause problems like this.  Your macro variable won't be updated (and I'm a bit surprised it's not throwing an error about the `%do` loop, personally).

```
rsubmit;

%macro GMV;
%do year=1970 %to 2015;
data home.historical_returns_&year;
set home.crspdata;
where (year <= &year - 1) and (year >= &year - 5);
returns_count + 1;
by id year;
if first.id or missing(tot_ret) then returns_count = 1;
run;
%end;

%mend GMV;

%GMV
endrsubmit;
```

Put the whole macro in the rsubmit to get the result you're looking for - or put the whole rsubmit in the macro (not as good of an idea in my opinion, though Tom in comments notes that it might be the safer option in some cases).

Comment: As an irrelevant-to-the-question addon: for most use cases, you shouldn't have to create datasets like this.  One dataset with a BY group for dataset-year can do most of what you want in cases where you're doing this.

Comment: Putting a macro definition inside of an RSUBMIT block can cause trouble.  SAS seems to get confused sometimes when trying to sent the code over to the other side an unexpected token breaks can be introduced.  I am not sure if this issue has ever been fixed.  It is a pain to debug.  Better to upload the definition code and %INC it on the remote side.

Comment: Better not to write the code this way at all I suppose... I don't think I've ever had trouble with this style though, although it's been a few years since I had to use RSUBMIT.  I've definitely run code that involved sending a macro over RSUBMIT and had no issues.  But good to know there could be some.

Comment: The system we had that got burned by this wrapped everything into an autocall macro. So it might be the combination of the rsubmit block with the macro definition being embedded inside of the execution of another macro that confused SAS.

Comment: Joe: This is part of a larger set of code. But I am still learning and this is the easiest way I have found to do it.

Comment: Interesting fact though. I ran the Joe's code with the rsubmit outside the %macro and it ran the code properly before sending an error code.  4094  endrsubmit;
      ----------
      180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.     /////// Taking out the endrsubmit; works to eliminate the error.

Comment: Might need a semicolon on GMV call to avoid SAS being confused.

Comment: And as far as this approach - if you are doing a regression or bootstrap or similar, Google 'Don't be Loopy' for advice on a better way (which applies to a lot of analyses).  BY group processing is one of SAS's best and most powerful features.

Comment: @joe Thank you. I will.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference a macro variable in the code that you `RSUBMIT` then the macro variable needs to exist in the remote session.

```
%macro GMV(start,end);
   %local year;
   %do year=&start %to &end;
      %syslput year=&year;
      rsubmit;
       data home.historical_returns_&year;
         set home.crspdata;
         by id year;
         where (year <= &year - 1) and (year >= &year - 5);
         returns_count + 1;
         if first.id or missing(tot_ret) then returns_count = 1;
       run;
     endrsubmit;
   %end;
 %mend GMV;

 %GMV(1970,2015);
```

Comment: Code like this works fine and I have used it. However, macros cannot be compiled and macro variables cannot be assigned between the RSUBMIT and ENDRSUBMIT (on the remote server). The only reason &YEAR is available is because of the %SYSLPUT. You can send a compiled macro using %SYSLPUT, but the macro quoting usually makes it more trouble than it is worth.